# Flutter: is there a way to open the keyboard in English?

Tags: flutter

Is there a way in Flutter to force that the keyboard which opens once I click the `TextForm` is in English?

I want a `TextField` to contain only English characters. Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following to open default keyboard app with predefined language.

```
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
```

---

There is no way to launch the keyboard in particular language. Users have to do that from their end in keyboard settings. However you may use the `RegExp` to check if all the characters are in English.

Comment: Well, I was trying to give a suggestion actually. It worked for me when I set autofocus = true . I my case, I had a search on app bar and i had to open keyboard when I click the search button on the side of search text input.

Comment: In that case, you need to use `focusNode` property and call `requestFocus(focusNode)`, the solution works in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

May be this helps!

```
SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.show');
```

whenever requestFocus is invoked to prevent this situation:

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't a way to launch the keyboard in a language.

To open keyboard with the predefined language you need to enable `autoFocus` in the `TextField` widget like this:

```dart
TextField(
autofocus: true,
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('PROVIDE FOCUS'),
            onPressed: () {
              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode);
              SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.show');
            },
          ),
          IgnorePointer(
            child: TextField(
              focusNode: _focusNode,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```